# Is there a Spring HandlerAdapter implementation for Struts?

Tags: spring, struts

This is just a curiosity question.  I know that Spring can be used in a Struts ActionServlet (sp?) via certain means, but I was wondering if there was a HandlerAdapter that allowed old Struts code to be ported immediately to a Spring DispatcherServlet to use the DispatcherServlet as the front controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the Spring-Struts interface code is in the [org.springframework.web.struts](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/struts/package-summary.html) package, and there's no `HandlerAdapter` implementation in there, just the delegation stuff like [DelegatingRequestProcessor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/struts/DelegatingRequestProcessor.html).

I suppose the Struts framework is just too awful even for Spring's integration abilities.